# Replace String in column of DataFrame with matching float from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following two DataFrames:

```
fx = {'FX_Pairs': ['EUR', 'USD', 'GBP'],
        'FX_Rate': [0.92, 1, 0.78]}



df = {'Company': ['LVMH', 'Apple', 'Shell'],
      'FX_Rate': ['EUR', 'USD', 'GBP'],}

fx_df = pd.DataFrame(fx)
df_df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I would like to replace the "FX_Rate" column in the df Dataframe with the corresponding "FX_Rates" values in the fx Dataframe.

I tried using

```
df = df_df.merge(fx_df, on="FX_Rate", how="left")
```

which worked but it adds another column, whereas I want to replace the column.

Comment: Please consider using the proper formatting for the code

Answer (score 2):

You can just drop any extra columns after merge. And while merging assign appropriate suffixes to right and left hand side dataframes

```
df_df \
    .merge(fx_df,
           right_on="FX_Pairs",
           left_on="FX_Rate",
           how="left",
           suffixes=["_txt", ""]) \
    .drop(["FX_Rate_txt", "FX_Pairs"], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Company  FX_Rate
0    LVMH     0.92
1   Apple     1.00
2   Shell     0.78
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` method:

```
df_df.replace({'FX_Rate':dict(fx_df.itertuples(False))}, inplace = True)
df_df
  Company  FX_Rate
0    LVMH     0.92
1   Apple     1.00
2   Shell     0.78
```